# Handle multiple numpy ndarrays (8-bit int)

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I wish to create a loop process where I go through some functions that produce as an output a numpy ndarrays (8-bit int). These would approximately be 1500 iterations. Specifically the code will have the form:

```
def process0(X_variable):
    output1 = process1(X_variable)
    output2 = process2(output1)
    final_out = process3(output2)
    return final_out 


for number in range(len(totals)):
    X_variable = various[number]
    final_out = process0(X_variable)
```

The final_out is a 8-bit int numpy ndarray, with a possible form (130, 118, 118) but in general the dimensions might change on each iteration.
Is there a way to save these ndarrays somewhere? And call them the next time I wish to manipulate them?

Comment: Why not save them in variables? Or in a list?

Comment: ```process0``` won't do anything unless you call it.  There are numerous containers that objects can be *saved* in - you just have to find one that fits your process the best.  [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html), as well as lists, dicts and tupels.

Comment: I am brand new in python so any suggestions would be well appreciated. My question is final_out isn't already a variable? So I have to modify final_out to have that form final_out[number] ??

Comment: yeah, @wwii sorry. I fixed it now

Comment: You have to assign the return value of the function to something, ```alpha = process0(29)```, or store it in something ```my_list.append(process0(29))```.

Comment: [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: If you mean persistence, numpy arrays have methods to save them as either text or binary